# When opening an Excel file, in which order are the Workbook events triggered?

Tags: excel, vba, events

I'm looking for informations to understand which events and in which order are triggered when opening an Excel workbook (e.g Worbook_Open, Workbook_Activate, Workbook_SheetActivate ...)
There are many events, but I did not find detailed documentation for them
Thanks

Comment: I don't know and there probably is information but you could always just test it. Put like a msgbox in each stating which one it is and see which order they pop up in. Something like that. Edit: Quick search led me here: https://pixcels.nl/events-in-workbooks/

Comment: Hi Simon. This is the most valuable information I ever read on Events sequence at Excel opening. Many Thanks !